# Como contar a quantidade de registros de uma seleçao em uma tabela

Tags: sql

Eu fiz uma seleçao de todos os resultados de uma tabela. O que eu preciso é mostrar a quantidade desses resultados. No meu caso, preciso mostrar quantas especialidades diferentes existem

```
SELECT "especialidade" FROM funcionarios GROUP BY "especialidade"
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para "Quantas especialidades diferentes existem", Simples:

```
select 
    count(distinct especialidade) as qtd_especialidade
from funcionarios
```

ou para "Quantos registros há por especialidade:

```
select 
    especialidade,
    count(*) as qtd
from funcionarios group by especialidade
```

Comment: Deu certo! E como eu faço pra renomear a coluna daí?

Comment: alterei a resposta, veja

Comment: @DiegoSoares, lembra de marcar a resposta como correta, se resolveu o problema ;)

Answer (score 2):

@DiegoSoares Podes utilizar a seguinte query:

1- Retornar o total de registos
select Especialidade = count(distinct especialidade) 
from funcionarios

2- agrupado por tipo de especialidade
select qtd = count(distinct especialidade) , especialidade
from funcionarios
Group by especialidade

3- filtrado por especialidade
select qtd = count(distinct especialidade) 
Where especialidade = "filtro a colocar"
from funcionarios

4- filtrado e agrupado
select qtd = count(distinct especialidade) 
Where especialidade = "filtro 1 a colocar"
from funcionarios
Union all
select qtd = count(distinct especialidade) 
Where especialidade = "filtro 2 a colocar"
from funcionarios

5- varias especialidades
select qtd = count(distinct especialidade) 
Where especialidade in ("filtro a colocar", "filtro 2")
from funcionarios